# virusscan a stream before storing on disk

Tags: c#, file, upload, stream, virus

I've found a lot of solutions of how to scan uploaded files. My issue is this: Every single solution on internet starts scanning after a stream is saved as a file.

My Question: Can a file harm the server at the moment its stored at the disk? If so, is it possible to viruscheck an uploaded stream before storing it on the harddrive?

Comment: a thing i forgot to mention: I'm using a mvc c# project for uploading files.

Comment: That's almost certainly a vendor specific feature (if it exists at all). Why not take exclusive access to the file while you're writing it?

Comment: It's not possible to scan the stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file is just a series of bytes. The OS isn't going to run that file when you save it to disk. Saving it to disk won't harm you, but make sure you remove that file when you detect a virus.

I don't think you can easily verify a stream, since virus scanners are most often processes that deal with files.

Comment: Ok i solved the issue by storing the stream in a temp directory to scan and then move it to the correct directory (if no virusses were found).

Comment: how did you store stream? as file?

Comment: my assumption is if virus scanner is enabled than on file save, it will automatically scan file and in case of virus it will remove it from system.